# Microsoft Test Runner stand alone

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, test-runner, manual-testing

Is there a stand alone version of the Microsoft Test Runner (The tool, that is started, when I run manual tests from the Microsoft Test Manager)? I want to assign Tests to Testers, but they should not have to install the whole Test Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Testers need a Test Pro license, at least, to run manual tests. In that sense they need to be able to install MTM. However, you can run manual tests from Web Access, which doesn't need MTM to be installed. Be aware that you cannot use data collectors if you are using the Web Access test runner.